# Customize SharePoint OOTB Alert Email in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

I wanted to know how to get the alerts record using jquery in SharePoint page I know alerttemplate.xml will not be accessible to me. So, I am thinking of communicating directly from the List/ Storage where alerts record get saved.

Answer (score 0):

The alert template is not accessible.

You'll want to use a Flow/PowerApp/Workflow to handle this instead if you have a custom email you'd like to send on item creation/change.

More complex options would be remote event receivers or scheduled CSOM jobs scanning for new/changes.